How do I fix a 'adb: failed to stat' error?
I am using WSL2 and trying to do a build with Expo on the blank template with a test Agora.io integration. Unfortunately I am running into an error with ADB.

The build is successful, however trying to put it on the connected device (a Pixel 6a, listed correctly when  I run adb devices) results in an error

If it is difficult to read the error given is:
Error: adb: failed to stat /mnt/c/Users/[project directory]/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk: No such file or directory
Not really sure how to approach this error. I tried restarting my phone and computer, ran java -version to ensure Java was correctly installed in my PATH and accessible, I reran the build process multiple times, and checked the SDK path in my environment variables.
I also do not have the app installed on my phone at all, so there should not be a conflict from having the same package name.
Unfortunately I cannot fully test with Expo Go because I am using native modules. So I need to build the app to test it.
Any ideas?
Thank you for your time.
